# How can we get the last element of the filtered json records with json path

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

The data:

```json
{
  token : "xxxx"
  files: [
    {
      id : 1,
      deleted: true
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      deleted: false
    },
    {
      id : 3,
      deleted: false
    }
]
}
```

I am using the json path

```
$..files[?(@.deleted==false)].id
```

It is giving all the ids but I only want last one how to get within the jsonpath itself.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The path you have should be returning `id`s 2 and 3, but not 1.

If you just want the last element, you can use a negative index, like `[-1]`.

Let's break down the path you have.

```
$                                 // start of the path, selects the data root
 ..files                          // recursively find all "files" properties (see below)
        [?(                       // start filter expression
           @.deleted==false       // select nodes with "deleted" property value false
                           )]     // end filter expression
                             .id  // select "id" property for every node found
```

You probably only need `.files` (one dot) here since it doesn't look like you need the recursive search, similar to how you've done `.id`.

```
$.files[-1].id
```

This will give the last `id` in the list, but it may not be `deleted==false`.  To get that, you'll need to use the path you have, but you'll also need to just select the last one in code.

Depending on the implementation you're using, you *may* be able to just tack on the `[-1]` at the end, but try it first.  It's not a "standard" behavior, though.

Comment: It isn't working by giving the [-1] at the end

Comment: Is there a way which can return the list in reverse orderusing json path

Comment: No, JSON Path doesn't have a reversing feature.